# Windows stucks on logon - found solution but didn't understood why it works

Tags: windows, group-policy, login

Helo!
I have some problem with Windows stucks on logon – luckily I have found solution, but I could not understand why it work and I’m hope someone could explain it to me.
So my situation was as follows:
In my network, there is single AD with W2012R2. Some users are located in another subnet (but without defining it in AD). They are simply connected to main network via 1Gb link, so there is no need to define separate site for it. On this separate network there is also separate DHCP server pointing to DNS server on AD server in main site.
From time to time, users from this remote network complained that their computers (Windows 10) stucks on logon. After investigating problem I have found that:

- disconnecting network adapter for minute or two allow for login
- login process probably stuck on processing GPO and manually invoking “gpupdate /force” also stucks
- after unsuccessfully trying many different ways to solve problem (including removing cached credentials for system account and disjoining computer from AD domain and then rejoining it back) I have found that after switching computer from wired to wireless connection problem is gone as long as computer uses wireless connection. Returning back to wired connection, bring problem back. There is no difference between wired and wireless connection - the same subnet, the same VLAN and the same IP configuration obtained from DHCP (obviously with different IP address, but the same network, mask, gateway, DNS, etc.)

And now most strange part for me:

- I have switched back to wired connection with DHCP configuration – problem occours
- changed IP configuration from DHCP to manual – with different IP address – problem gone!
- changed IP back to DHCP configuration (it obtained the same IP, as previously) – it still works! No problems!

I must emphasize that, there is no firewall involved, and “wired vs wireless” case was probably (almost for sure) a case of “one network adapter vs another one”. It wasn’t even a matter of IP address (as finally it start working with exactly the same IP as on beginning) but rather a matter of some deepper configurations, associated with particular network adapter.

I ‘would be very happy if I could understood why this simple action (changing network IP configuration from DHCP to manual and back to DHCP) solved this quite common problem (it happens quite often and other actions usually doesn’t help).

Comment: Could be a thousand things. Have you checked the event log for errors?

Comment: Sure, but there się nothing special. Only errors about failed GPO update

Comment: After "logging on" with the wired connection, are you able to ping your domain controllers by short name and by FQDN?

Comment: Yes. For both connections there were no differences in IP configuration and system functioning, except problem with gpo updates.